# Creating a Scrollable Span

Tags: css

I have the following DIV which primarily has two sections - left and right. The right section has some images and I am not really worried about that. It's the span class="left" that's worrying. I am not able to add a scrollbar to it.

```
<div id="about">
        <span class="quoted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris </span><br/>

        <span class="left"><span class="paragraph_title">ABOUT</span><br/>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"<br/><br/>
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat<br/><br/>

        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciun<br/><br/>       

        </span>

        <div class="right">
            <ul>
                <li><span class="paragraph_title">RECENT ACTIVITIES</span></li>
                <li><a href="" data-rel="prettyPhoto[recents]" title="" class="rollover"><img src="" alt="recent project"/></a><a href="#" target="_blank">www.stackoverflow.com</a></li>
                <li><a href="" data-rel="prettyPhoto[recents]" title="" class="rollover"><img src="" alt="recent project"/></a><a href="#" target="_blank">www.stackoverflow.com</a></li>
                <li><a href="" data-rel="prettyPhoto[recents]" title="" class="rollover"><img src="" alt="recent project"/></a><a href="#" target="_blank">www.stackoverflow.com</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and some CSS for the About Div that goes as

```
#about {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    top: 210px;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    z-index: 8;
    overflow: auto;
}

#about .quoted {
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 27px;
    color: #4bc9f2; 
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #000;
}

#about .paragraph_title {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #4bc9f2; 
    line-height: 28px;
}

#about .left {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #fff;    
    float: left;
    padding: 60px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 490px;
}
```

How can I add a scroll bar to the Span tag and make it Scroll Vertically and NOT horizontally. You can assume the Span height to be anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I add a scroll bar to the Span tag and make it Scroll Vertically and NOT horizontally. You can assume the Span height to be anything.

In order to do this for a span, you'll need those CSS

```
display: block;
overflow: auto;
```

Then, you might need to apply a height if the span use a float or if there isn't an appropriate container.

Answer (score 2):

Give height and overflow properties

```
style="height: 114px;overflow: scroll !important;"
```

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not remembering wrong, vertical scroll could be done as:

```
overflow-y:scroll
```